# Show do not refresh message/page while payment details are fetched PayPal Checkout Button

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, paypal-buttons

I am integrating paypal express checkout with v2 php checkout sdk. I am able to make transaction complete and redirect user to a thankyou page and save the details to db, but when user pay through paypal secure window and it closes, paypal processes the payment and my getorder function gets fetched, at this time there is significant delay and user sits on checkout page with no indication what is happening, after few seconds, page refreshes and user is redirected to thankyou page for payment successful.

Now my question is how should I display a message to user to do not refresh the page or close the window while the payment details are fetched.
Or is there any way I can send the user to another page which tells him to wait when paypal button is clicked and then it is processed.

Thanks

**My PayPal Button Code:**

```
paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('amount', document.getElementById("amount_paypal").value);
            formData.append('currency_code', document.getElementById("currency_code_paypal").value);
            formData.append('refrence_id', document.getElementById("refrence_id_paypal").value);
            formData.append('event_id', document.getElementById("event_id_paypal").value);
            formData.append('description', document.getElementById("description_paypal").value);

            return fetch('../paypal/createorder.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(resJson) {
                return resJson.result.id;
            });
        },
        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                return fetch('../paypal/getorder.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        orderID: data.orderID
                    })
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if (!res.ok)
                        throw new Error('Something Went Wrong!');
                    window.location = "../paypal/thankyou.php";
                });
            });
        },
        experience: {
            input_fields: {
                no_shipping: 1
            },
        },
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to do a server-side integration.

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This way, the buyer approves the payment @ paypal, then clicks a final "Pay Now" / "Place Order" button on your site that calls your server, which then calls paypal to execute/capture the transaction, and your server has an immediate record of the completed transaction, and then responds so that your page displays a thank you message to the customer with the completed transaction.

This way, it is impossible for there to be a completed transaction w/o your server knowing about it, and w/o the customer seeing a thank you message